# How can I save cloth settings as a preset?

Tags: cloth-simulation

It's a bit of a silly question, but I have a cloth setup, like just the general cloth settings, and want to save it as a preset, because if I turn off the cloth and turn it on, the settings are set to default, so they are reset. Plus I want to name that setup and use it for multiple situations.

You can suggest an addon if there is one for such.

Answer (score 3):

Use this button underlined in green in the cloth panel:

[image]

Give a name to the preset and use the <kbd>+</kbd> button.